# How to create a custom markup for a views-block?

Tags: views, blocks, 8, theming

I'm trying to understand the templating system of Drupal 8, allready did some basic stuff. My next step is trying to create a template to mark up a list generated by a view.

Here's what I've done so far:

I created:

- A Content Type, with 3 fields: Title, Body, Link
- Some (5) content entries with this Content Type
- A View (Block) that lists all of the entries of this Content Type.

In Block layout I placed the View-block in a custom Region (werk_items)
(configured in the my-theme.info.yml file.)

Than I created a page template (page--node--23.html.twig) that includes this region, like so

{{ page.werk_items }}

When I go to the corresponding URL all works well and all of the content is displayed.

Now my question is: How to extract the variables to create a custom markup for the view content?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create custom markup/template for that particular view of content type then create file and name it as **views-view-fields--[view-name]--page/block.html.twig** and save it in template directory of your theme.

Now to get the variable just goto the content type -> manage fields. There you will find the machine names of fields. those are the variable you need to place in html structure like this 

**{{ fields.field-machine-name.content }}**

 Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see all the variables available in the Twig template you can just call [dump Twig function](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/dump.html) without any parameters:

```
{{ dump() }}
```

In case you want to modify the markup inside the region or the blocks you should override corresponding templates instead of trying to modify the render array inside your page template.